# JSON serialization error in Django Rest Framework when using pagination

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I just tried to add pagination using `pagination_class = TenItemsSetPagination` to my class-based-view.
As a result, I get an error trying to access my endpoint: `<Response status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8"> is not JSON serializable`

views.py:

```
class AllCartsView(ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    authentication_classes = []
    queryset = Cart.objects.all()

    serializer_class = carts_serializers.DataCartSerializer
    renderer_classes = (BrowsableAPIRenderer, JSONRenderer,)
    pagination_class = TenItemsSetPagination

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

paginators.py

```
class TenItemsSetPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10
```

- Versions : Django 1.9.9 / DRF 3.3

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: how are your returning the response? Please share the code of your view

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that using `(ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView)` instead of `(ListAPIView)` is responsible for the error.